# Test if a child node exists (without getting NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

```xml
<root>
  <channel>
    <one>example</one>
    <two>example2</two>
  </channel>
  <channel>
    <one>example</one>
  </channel>
</root>
```

In the second node, I don't have a `<two>` node. If I use this: `root.channel.two` obviously I get the error "Method missing". How can I check to avoid this error? What is the conditional statement I would use?

Comment: For those who don't know, `root.channel` is also an error, unless using Nokogiri's [Slop](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#slop).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Technique 1: Rescue Any Error

```
require 'nokogiri'
d = Nokogiri.XML("<foo><bar /></foo>")
bad = d.root.bar            #=> undefined method `bar' for #<...> (NoMethodError)
d.slop!           
yay = d.root.bar            #=> #<... name="bar">
bad = d.root.xxx            #=> undefined method `xxx' for #<...> (NoMethodError)
yay = d.root.xxx rescue nil #=> nil
```

### Technique 2: Look Before Leaping (aka Don't Use Slop)

```
%w[ bar xxx ].each do |node_name|
  if n = d.root.at_xpath(node_name)
    puts "Yay! #{n}"
  else
    puts "No node named #{node_name}"
  end
end
#=> Yay! <bar/>
#=> No node named xxx
```

The (no-slop) code `some_node.at_xpath("foo")` is identical to `some_node.foo` when using slop, except that it returns `nil` when no child node with that name exists. Indeed, the implementation of Slop just calls `xpath` for the element name: if it finds many elements, you get that Nodeset; if it finds only one element, it gives you that; if it finds no elements, it raises the `NoMethodError`. The important bits look like this:

```
def method_missing( name )
  list = xpath(name)
  if list.empty?
    super                 # NoMethodError unless someone else handles this
  elsif list.length == 1
    list.first            # Since we only found one element, return that
  else
    list                  # ...otherwise return the whole list
  end
end
```

Here's what the Nokogiri documents say about Slop (in the footnotes):

> Don’t use this.
>   No, really, don’t use this. If you use it, don’t report bugs.
>   You’ve been warned!

In general, XPath is way more powerful and faster than slop traversal. For example, if you want to iterate over every `<two>` node, you can do:

```
d.xpath('/root/channel/two').each do |two|
  # This will only find nodes that exist
end
```

If you describe what you really need to do in the end, we can help you craft better code. In my personal opinion Slop is generally a less-effective way to traverse a document.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple way of doing this:

```
  xml = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Auckland+New+Zealand"))

  @current_conditions = xml.xpath("//current_conditions")

  if @current_conditions.empty?
    @display_weather = 0
  else
    @display_weather = 1
  end
```