# Nokogiri, only if exists in file

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Actually im working with Nokogiri:

```
gruppe.css('diagnosen_liste>diagnose').each do |diagnose|
    cesc = diagnose.css('icd_code')[0]
    cesc2 = diagnose.css('bezeichnung')[0]
  cesc3 = diagnose.css('abrechenbar')[0]
  cesc4 = diagnose.css('geschlechtsbezug')[0]
    sub = ""
  diagnose.css('diagnosethesaurus_liste>diagnosethesaurus').each do |subcategory|
    sub << "#{subcategory['V']};"
  end
    arr << "Icd3.create!({:nummer => '#{cesc['V']}', :bezeichnung => '#{cesc2['V']}', :icd2_id => '#{b.to_s}', :sub => '#{sub}', :abrechenbar =>'#{cesc3['V']}', :geschlechtsbezug =>'#{cesc4['V']}'})" + "\n"
end
```

My problem is that:

```
cesc4 = diagnose.css('geschlechtsbezug')[0]
```

Is not avaible in each diagnoses. So im trying to make such an function like

**If** diagnose.css('geschlechtsbezug')[0]  **not exist,** cesc4 = nil

Maybe someone can say me how to write this code! Thanks!

Comment: **does not exist** means?

Comment: Sorry not exists! Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511586/test-if-a-child-node-exists-without-getting-nomethoderror

Comment: why you are using `[0]` ?

Comment: It does not make sense..Are you interested only thr first element always?

Comment: Yes! But my actual issue is how i can check if the element 'geschlechtsbezug' is defined in an diagnose? DO you understand?

Comment: You need to show a stripped-down sample of the XML.

Comment: @thetinMan simply <geschlechtsbezug V="w"/> does not exist in all diagnose only in some diagnose!

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to do:

```
cesc4 = diagnose.at('geschlechtsbezug')['V'] rescue nil
```

Some people don't like the rescue, but to me it's the most straightforward. It's immediately obvious to me what's happening there when I read that, with the ternary or if/else, not so much.

Answer (score 2):

As you are interested with first element only, so you can use `#at_css` instead of `#css`.Thus you can do code as below:

```
cesc4 = diagnose.at_css('geschlechtsbezug')
```

If `geschlechtsbezug` not found,then `cesc4` will automatically be set to `nil`.

**Update**

> The problem is that my file looks like this:  Means that i only want ['V']

Then I would do as below:

```
 cesc4 = diagnose.at_css('geschlechtsbezug')
 cesc4 &&= cesc4['V']
```

Comment: The problem is that my file looks like this: <geschlechtsbezug V="w"/> Means that i only want ['V']. And when i try to run diagnose.at_css('geschlechtsbezug')['V] and at_css('geschlechtsbezug') is nil i get an error!

Comment: Yes that is the case!! geschlechtsbezug does not exist in all diagnose!!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this as simple as:

```
cesc4 = diagnose.css('geschlechtsbezug').empty? ? nil : diagnose.css('geschlechtsbezug')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this, easy code:

```
if diagnose.at_css('geschlechtsbezug') == nil
cesc4 = diagnose.at_css('geschlechtsbezug')
else
cesc4 = diagnose.css('geschlechtsbezug')[0]['V']
end
```

Thanks to @Priti for some helpfull points!